# Angular change the wrapper for a component conditionally

Tags: angular

I have a component where the HTML is like this:

```
<app-cancel-apply (onApply)="onApply()" (onCancel)="onCancel()">
  <!-- 100+ lines of HTML here -->
</app-cancel-apply>
```

But depending on a boolean @Input flag named `okOnly` sometimes I want:

```
<app-ok (onOk)="onCancel()">
  <!-- The exact same 100+ lines of HTML here -->
</app-ok>
```

How can I conditionally change the outer wrapper without creating a new component and copying and pasting the 100+ lines of HTML? Thanks

I'm thinking I could use content projection (could be wrong) but I'm already using content projection to project the 100+ lines of HTML. Doing it twice seems crazy.

Comment: `<!-- 100+ lines of HTML here -->` can be a template

Comment: nice thinking, please add an answer and I will +1 it ... didn't think of that ... will accept if nothing better comes along

Comment: More obvious solution would be to create a component containing the 100+ lines.

Comment: another good comment, add answer if you want a +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a common template for the inner content:

```
<ng-template #innerContent>
  <!-- 100+ lines of HTML here -->
</ng-template>
```

And insert it with a template outlet in the appropriate container, which can be set with `ngIf...else`:

```
<app-ok *ngIf="okOnly; else cancelTemplate" (onOk)="onCancel()">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="innerContent"></ng-container>
</app-ok>

<ng-template #cancelTemplate>
  <app-cancel-apply (onApply)="onApply()" (onCancel)="onCancel()">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="innerContent"></ng-container>
  </app-cancel-apply>
</ng-template>
```